# Toggling text with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a button that will make text disappear when clicked, accompanied by an alert, and then make it reappear accompanied by a different alert when clicked again. The code I have so far is:

```
$(".great-grandma-button").click(function(){
      $("#great-grandma").find("h1").toggle();
      alert("Grandma's Gone!");
    });
```

so making the text disappear and reappear is easy enough, the initial alert is simple as well so really I just need to know how to have a different alert associated with the second click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `.toggle()` function is already modifying the element's visiblity, you can use the `.is(':visible')` function on said element for something like this:

```
$(".great-grandma-button").on('click', function(e) {
    var h1 = $("#great-grandma").find("h1");
    h1.toggle();
    if (h1.is(':visible')) {
        alert("The thing is visible.");
    } else {
        alert("The thing is NOT visible");
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H4LHY/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable, or add a class to one of the elements, depending on how many you have it will change how easy each solution is.

```
var grandmaVisable = true;
$(".great-grandma-button").click(function(){
      $("#great-grandma").find("h1").toggle();
      if (grandmaVisable == true) {
        grandmaVisable = false;
        alert("Grandma's Gone!");
      } else {
        grandmaVisable = true;
        alert("Grandma's Back!");
      }
    });
```

A better way though would be to just use jQuery's `.toggleClass()` toggle a CSS class onto the hidden one.  The CSS for that class could then mark it as hidden.

If you need to do other things when the class is hidden / shown then you could use `.hasClass()` to see if the flag for hidden is present or not.

https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use one of jQuery functions or selectors to check whether the content is currently visible (i.e. `$('h1').is(":visible")` or just use this selector `$('h1:visible')`) or you can make a use of the variable as follows:

```
var isVisible = true;
$(".great-grandma-button").click(function(){
  $("#great-grandma").find("h1").toggle();
  if (isVisible) {
    alert("Grandma's Gone!");
  } else {
    alert("Grandma's Back!");
  }
  isVisible = !isVisible;
});
```